# How do I get the disk usage (IO) of processes in UNIX?

Tags: c++, unix, io, disk

I need to get the IO usage on the disk of processes in UNIX.
I need to get it from another c++ process, better not from unix command lines but from some light c++ library.
Also, if you have some nice way to know the throughput of network that goes through a process (again, not via command lines) it will also be great.
Can you please recommend something?
Thanks

Comment: check the manual page of `time`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `time` command in order to show all sort of I/O statistics. check the `formating the output` section

what you are looking for will probably be like this:

```
time -f "Input: %I \noutput: %O" <some-program>
```

that's command line, but you can embed it in a c++ program. [How to run a bash script from C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646217/how-to-run-a-bash-script-from-c-program/646225#646225)

Comment: This doesn't work on mac os x (which is UNIX), neither with `/usr/bin/time`, or bash or zsh builtin time.

Comment: @OlegGrenrus sorry, I automatically translate unix to linux. there is a command for mac named `gtime` : http://superuser.com/questions/196072/fully-featured-time-command-on-mac-os-x

Comment: The problem here is that you need to execute the process in advanced via time. I guess it acts like some kind of virtual machine or sandbox. I need an option to get the IO on already running program.

Comment: @user2963867 look this up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838190/mac-os-x-getting-detailed-process-information-specifically-its-launch-argument